# Why does this link in Stack Overflow help center take you to Stack Exchange Meta help center?

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

I have been reading through [Stack Overflow help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and noticed that this link points to an article in the Stack Exchange Meta help center instead of Stack Overflow's equivalent article.

In [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) under the heading **How can I get out of a question ban?**:

> [Deleting your questions will not help.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

takes you to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question instead of https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question.

I believe this is an error and such links should remain within the Stack Overflow help center in this case.

Comment: FWIW, the text is identical in both articles. I agree that the SO link should be used though.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in your question, the `/help/question-bans` page of the help center (network-wide) contains the quoted line, which has a link pointing to the MSE version of the "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" help center page (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) specifically. As a result, it takes users from the SO help center to the MSE one instead, resulting in some confusion.

I've fixed this help center article to use a relative link (`/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question`) instead. That way, this link will take SO users to the [corresponding help center article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). (I also made some other minor fixes to the article while I was at it.)